# The help text is missing a white space between two words

Tags: bug, status-completed

The text shown in [the Markdown help for the pre-formatted text](https://ell.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code) says:

> Indent four spaces to create an block of preformatted **textdisplayed** in a monospaced font

It should be "preformatted **text displayed** in a monospaced font"; there is a missing spaces.

Another Stack Exchange site like [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) doesn't show the same error. That help page actually uses a different sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed, will go out in the next deployment.

Grazie :-)

Comment: Congrats on becoming an employee!